# Removing Duplicate Tickets in Microstrategy based on Work Log Date

Tags: duplicates, microstrategy

I have a question regarding duplicates in Microstrategy.
I have a data set which has all tickets 'Not Closed' along with the 'Work Info Work Log Date' field added.  Work Info Work Log Date column shows every timestamp a ticket was updated, which ultimately leads to duplicate rows.  What I want to know is if there is a way I can remove duplicates prior to exporting my report.  The function I need is similar to this If/then/else statement below.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
>  IF status <> "Assigned" and "Work Info Work Log Date" = ""
>     THEN,DEL ROW (what this is doing is obviously checking if a ticket is not in "Assigned" Status, additionally, if the Work Info Work Log
> Date is blank, then delete the entire row).
>      ELSE Unfilter ALL, sort "Work Info Work Log Date" from Newest to Oldest, sort Ticket Number from A-Z, then remove All duplicates.
>      END
```

Thank you for the help!

P

else, Sort Work Info Work Log Date Newest to Oldest
Sort Ticket # in Ascending Order
Remove Duplicates

Answer (score 0):

What if you take the max(log date) for each ticket?